# Why "should.strictEqual" in should.js doesn't work?

Tags: mocha.js, should.js

According to [should.js Spec](https://github.com/visionmedia/should.js#equal) this should work:

```
should.strictEqual(shape.code, code)
```

but I get:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'strictEqual'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like an error in the documentation. `equal` is defined [in the script](https://github.com/visionmedia/should.js/blob/master/lib/should.js) as "strict equal":

```
/**
 * Assert strict equal.
 *
 * @param {Mixed} val
 * @param {String} description
 * @api public
 */

equal: function(val, desc){
  this.assert(
      val.valueOf() === this.obj
    , 'expected ' + this.inspect + ' to equal ' + i(val) + (desc ? " | " + desc : "")
    , 'expected ' + this.inspect + ' to not equal ' + i(val) + (desc ? " | " + desc : "")
    , val);
  return this;
},
```

...and `strictEqual` does not appear in the script.

Answer (score 1):

Should.js offers **.equal**() to check for identity (===), and **.eql**() to check for equality (==).

Reference:
https://github.com/visionmedia/should.js/blob/9feffef939197002ce16708c27036f7f744e8131/lib/should.js#L277-L309